# Self referencing XML tree to create a multi-tier unordered list

Tags: php, xml, recursion

My objective is to create navigation menu that has unlimited depth tree.  I can successfully generate the top 2 levels.  The first (Top level) is using a PHP array that is not stored within the XML file.  The second is generated from a flat xml file. The main problem is successful recursion.

Here is the XML structure:

```
<articles>
    <article>
        <menu parent="Insurance" label="Business" target="#" show="true" />
        <data />
        <body />
    </article>
    <article>
        <menu parent="Resources" label="Videos" target="content.php#videos" show="true" />
        <data />
        <body />
    </article>
    <article>
        <menu parent="Business" label="Disability" target="content.php#disability" show="true" />
        <data />
        <body />
    </article>
    <article>
        <menu parent="Business" label="Liability" target="content.php#liability" show="true" />
        <data />
        <body />
    </article>

</articles>
```

I am using # in my target attribute to identify if a new list (sub-menu) needs to be started.

The PHP code that I receive success with outputting the correct information is:

```
    $objXMLMenu = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
    foreach ($mainmenu as $menuparent) {  //Main Array

        echo "<li><a href=\"" .$maintargets[$i]. "\">". $menuparent ."</a>\n";  // Top Menu array. I use 2 for clarity
        if ($maintargets[$i] == "#"){


            //Open the ULs for filling
            echo "\t<ul>\n";

    // Start function here?

            foreach($objXMLMenu->article as $art){

                foreach($art->menu as $menuitem){

                    if($menuitem['parent'] == $menuparent){ //Compare to Main Array

                        if ($menuitem['show'] == "true"){

                            if($menuitem['target'] == "#"){  //A Submenu exits here
                                echo "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . "\" >" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                                echo "\t\t\t<ul>\n";
                                //Run XMLQUERY match? As a 

                                echo "\t\t\t</ul>\n";
                            }else{
                                echo "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . " \"rel=\"ajax\">" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            //Close Middle Menus
            echo "\t</ul>";
        }
        $i++;
        //close Top Level Menu Item
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
//<UL> Footer
echo "\t</ul>\n</div>\n";
```

In an attempt to make it a recursive function I receive an error with my 1st foreach statement, which suggests to me I should switch to DOM & XPATH instead of simplexml. Here is the function I've come up with so far:

```
$objXMLMenu = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
// Start function here!
function mysubmenu($menuparent){
    foreach($objXMLMenu->article as $art){
        foreach($art->menu as $menuitem){
            if($menuitem['label'] == $menuparent){
            //Compare to Main Array
                if ($menuitem['show'] == "true"){

                    if($menuitem['target'] == "#"){
                        // ((ROOT)
                        //A Submenu exits here
                        $strResponse .= "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . " \">" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                        $strResponse .= "\t\t\t<ul>\n";

                        //xmlpath QUERY instead?
                        mysubmenu($menuitem['parent']);

                        $strResponse .= "\t\t\t</ul>\n";
                    }else{
                        $strResponse .= "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . " \"rel=\"ajax\">" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //insert counter to stop foreach loop after all records are posted.
    }
    return $strResponse; 
} //End Function
```

Recursion of this type is a new boundary for me.  Every example or explanation I have found involves XML tree's going deeper into the elements. A "depth" (counter) attribute is not an option. Since, I am facing a similar problem on a "postponed" project that truly is unlimited depth over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked on the procedural style did not work in the function.  My most troubling aspect was in [comparing SimpleXML objects](http://www.php.net/manual/kr/language.oop5.object-comparison.php#93968). There are about 5 lines that needed to be changed.  There is probably a simpler and faster way to get to this answer though for longer recursions.  But I found this works for now.

```
function mysubmenu($menuparent){
    $objXMLMenu = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
    foreach($objXMLMenu->article as $art){
        foreach($art->menu as $menuitem){

            if((string)$menuitem['parent'] == $menuparent){ 
                if ($menuitem['show'] == "true"){
                    if($menuitem['target'] == "#"){
                        echo "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . "\">" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                        echo "\t\t\t<ul>\n";
                        mysubmenu($menuitem['label']);
                        echo "\t\t\t</ul>\n";
                    }else{
                        echo "\t\t<li><a href=\"" . $menuitem['target'] . "\" rel=\"ajax\">" .$menuitem['label'] . "</a></li>\n";
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }

} //End Function
```